# Won't stop download music on localhost on the embed element of audio

Tags: javascript, html

I almost made it so I can have background music but when I go to my localhost it just downloads the music instead of playing it but in the full path one it plays it in the background so how can I prevent this from happening so it won't download in localhost?

Here is the code for it and the file name is actually "Sound.mp3" as well.

```
<embed src="Sound.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true"width="2" height="0" controls>
```

Any ideas of what do add to make it just play and not download?
I am actually working on a page that looks pretty cool and wanted to add background music cause it is actually an "under construction" page and wanted to make it look cooler with background music.

Comment: I'll leave discussions for the range of emotions auto-playing music on websites create. (Hint, they range from happy to homicidal). Have you considered using an actual `<audio>` element?They have great support in HTML5 and are the preffered way of doing things - `<embed>` is not exactly amongst the most used or loved tags. ;)
Also, questions providing a minimal, complete (working) example of the problem faced will garner better responses than those without one

Comment: Background music on websites was a good idea in 1997 (Or maybe not). But not in 2018.

Comment: @Heidel there are few very valid examples on which background music/audio/soundscape is very accepted in a website

Comment: @MacK For example?

Comment: @Heidel applies to any commercial or artistic website or any message you want to transmit through a website. In order on the tip of my tongue: Fox's Gotham promo website, arkade.london and Sortie en mer. Background audio isn't just playing awkward midi files on a text page.

Comment: @MacK Ok, I see your point. I'm not a gamer at all and not fan of tv-shows, so I have no idea about games and tv-shows promo sites, maybe it's actually appropriate there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefered way of adding audio in Html5 is to use the audio element.You can achieve them by using the following codes,

This code will play the Sound.mp3 file with the controllers displayed for the user. So the users can control the background music. With the autoplay attribute, the music will start automatically.

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"><source src="Sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>
```

If you don't wanna show the controls, you can simply remove the controls attribute. As follows,

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay"><source src="Sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /></audio>
```

But the song will autoplay because the autoplay attribute is added.

Unfortunately, not all browsers support mp3, so it's a good idea to include multiple versions of the file in different formats. As follows,

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay">
 <source src="Sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /> 
 <source src="Sound.wav" type="audio/wav" />
 <source src="Sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
 <p>This content is displayed by browsers that don't recognize the audio element.</p>
</audio>
```

Hope it helped. Good luck with your project. :)

**More Attributes**

**loop** -  Automatically loop (keep playing over and over).

Comment: Why did you add a new answer instead of editing your first one?

Comment: Sorry, I removed the old answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use  Tag to attach the attach the audio file to the html file.
If your audio file is Sound.mp3 then include it in `<audio>` tag.

```
<audio controls>
      <source src="Sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>
```

or use the below code

```
<audio src="Sound.mp3"> </audio>
```

[image]